# Understanding and proving the Lorentz invariance of the volume element in momentum space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, invariants

> By performing the relevant four-dimensional Lorentz transformations explicitly, demonstrate the Lorentz invariance of the volume element
> $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{d^3p}{2E_{\vec p}},\,\text{with}\,E_{\vec p}=\sqrt{\vec p^2+m^2}.$$

I am trying to solve this exercise. At first I thought I had to consider a generic Lorentz transformation: so 3 boosts and 3 rotations. But I can't find the expression for it. I guess I would have to multiply all 6 matrices. Carrol's book says it is so horrible that it is not worth writing it down. Anyway the book gives the boost along the $x$-axis and rotation around the $z$-axis matrices as examples of the usual Lorentz transformations (in coordinate space), but how do I use them to transform the momentum? Besides the question says to perform the **relevant** transformations, so maybe there is another way of doing it? Can you please guide me on how to do this or provide a reference where it's done?

Additionally I would appreciate if you can clear up also this quick related doubts

- Why isn't $dE$ in the given volume element, if we are dealing with 4 dimensions of space time or is it only the spacial part of the volume element? I would have expected something like $dp^1\,dp^2\,dp^3\,dE$ and maybe some constant. I am supposing a volume element in special relativity is 4-dimensional (?).
- I read in several places that $dp^4$ is obviously invariant. Why is that?
- If the question is asking for an explicit calculation, does that mean there is a quick implicit way of showing it too?

Comment: See the discussion of Eqs. (4.49)-(4.56) [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnChalker/theory/lecture-notes.pdf), and especially Eqs. (4.52) and (4.54).